# Logging an object to console.log

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a firefox add-on, and I'd like to log objects to `console.log`. Is there a way to expand the object description beyond the monotonic `[object Object]`? I mean if I have something like `{hello: "world"}` I'd like it's fields and values to be displayed like in node.js' console? Without actually implementing a loop iterating over the values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes just a simply JSON.stringify(object) will work. I use that quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Firefox nightly, you can do this:

1. set 'extensions.sdk.console.logLevel' in about:config to 'all'
2. use console.dir and look in the relatively new browser console:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/a6cb2922-a21d-431a-bc58-1800d4895ca1/d1f39b0af0b69f20c8d14e7cbb6e0d85

console.dir prints a nice expandable tree in the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Use ctrl+shift+j for console (but new firebug i think do it now too)

Remember console.log didnt work at SDK 1.14! See Official blog.
Use console.error

Comment: Wonderful. I'm using 1.14. Also, is there a way to expand the object on the CMD console log? I mean on the add on site, I want to see the whole object.

Comment: it just js.
Look at example at bottom
 https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html  or try to Json.parse function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse